# NullPointerException on MoreLikeThisComponent SOLR

Tags: solr, lucene, morelikethis

I'm trying to use the MoreLikeThis component under a suggest call, but I receive a npe every time (here's the stacktrace)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.MoreLikeThisComponent.process(MoreLikeThisComponent.java:127)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:295)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:177)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2503)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:710)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:516)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:382)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:326)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1751)...
```

and here's the config of my requestHandlers:

```
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="suggest">true</str>
<str name="suggest.count">10</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">default</str>
<str name="spellcheck">true</str>
<str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
<str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str>
<str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
<str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
<str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
<str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
<str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
<str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
<str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
<str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
<str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>

<str name="mlt">true</str>
<str name="mlt.fl">_text_</str>

<str name="hl">on</str>
<str name="hl.fl">content description title</str>
<str name="hl.preserveMulti">true</str>
<str name="hl.encoder">html</str>
<str name="hl.simple.pre">&lt;b&gt;</str>
<str name="hl.simple.post">&lt;/b&gt;</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
<str>suggest</str>
<str>spellcheck</str>
<str>mlt</str>
<str>highlight</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>

<requestHandler name="/mlt" class="solr.MoreLikeThisHandler"></requestHandler>
```

I also tried with

```
<str name="mlt">on</str>
```

When I call

```
/mlt?df=_text_&q=pann&mlt.fl=_text_
```

it works fine but with

```
/suggest?df=_text_&q=pann&mlt.fl=_text_
```

I got the npe

Comment: which Solr version you're using?

Comment: @Mysterion 7.3.1